# slime/emacs: Buffer that shows accessible variable bindings at point

Tags: emacs, binding, common-lisp, slime

Is there a way to show all accessible bindings at point (cursor)?

**more precisely:**
Is it possible (e.g.) to open a buffer and that buffer shows and updates the environment (context, set of all bindings) while I move the cursor within the slime REPL or my Common Lisp file?

Comment: Bbinding is a run-time concept (a lexical binding is a lexical association between a name and its value). Bindings are available only at run time (and in fact they can be shown by Slime inspecting the stack when there is an error), while the editor can operates only on the text (or the list representation) of the program.

Comment: But let's say I have `(defvar *x* 42)` and `(let ((x 3) (y 10)) ;body ...)` and the cursor is in the body of `LET`: would't it be clear (even without running the code) that I have access to the variables `*x*`, `x` and `y` and that I know at least that `x` ist bound to `3`  and `y` is bound to `10`?

Comment: what if you had instead `(let ((x (if (asdf/os:os-unix-p) 1 2))) x)`

Comment: @Frank, this can happen only through a partial evaluation (or static analysis) of the code, and the combination Emacs+Slime does not perform any evaluation of this type. What is "clear" for you (and for me) would require a much more integrated and sophisticated development environment, with a tight integration between editor and compiler/interpreter, and this is simply not available in the Emacs+Slime + Common Lisp interpreter/compiler.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi: Good point! As my question apparently doesn't make much sense it may as well be deleted. Thank's for the simple but good example.